# Python 'multitasking' need

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, python-3.x

I'm programming a audio program that reads a serial information sent by an arduino and play some songs if the serial information is "ok", and stop playing if is "not ok".
The problem is that I'm using the python library names "pyAudio", that reproduces a .wav sound as a stream of bytes, so there migth be a 'while' loop writing the stream of bytes every time, so the sound plays. 
Because of this while loop, I cannot do more anything meanwhile the execution of the code. But I need to read the serial information everytime to know if the sound must be played. Is there a way for me to do the serial reading in a way that the loop don't stop running?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be solved with the **threading** and **Queue** modules. There are many ways to handle this, but generally you create one thread for reading each blocking thing and pass the stuff they read to a main thread via the Queue so it can get processed.

Comment: There is also the source-filter-sink pattern with generators and coroutines - see http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/.

Comment: you could use [`callback` API to avoid the blocking loop](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o).

Comment: @tdelaney I want to execute a while loop (for reading the serial forever, and storing the data to a variable) but I also need to execute a while loop for playing the sound, byte by byte. How do I do this? I tried but it executes only one loop :(

Answer (score 0):

### A pseudocode draft:

```
def play_audio( buffer,play_controller ):
    # buffer is the audio buffer to play
    # play_controller.is_set lets you pause the playback
    while not_finished:
       if not play_controller.is_set():
           """
           The necessary code for playing a audio buffer/song
           """
       else: time.sleep(0.1)
#end

import threading
pause_handler = threading.Event()
player = threading.Thread(
               target = play_audio,
               args = ( buffer,pause_handler )
            )
player.start()
pause_handler.set() # this could pause playback
pause_handler.clear() # this could restart playback
```

If I understood you correctly. As you can see, this is pretty straigh forward.

#### If you are looking for a more reliable solution, you should look into `GStreamer` [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/).

Comment: Isn't more easy to do the multiprocessing for the serial reading? It would be much better for me!

Comment: You could fill up the buffer with the audio data in a serial manner, and use a `threading.Event()` to act as a pause or `ok` variable.